# Miniconda and celery

Tags: python, celery, miniconda

I have added celery in my miniconda distribution. But when I try to run it I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda2\Scripts\celery-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Miniconda2\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 29, in main
    from celery.bin.celery import main
ImportError: No module named celery
```

entering the python env through miniconda (C:\Miniconda2 python.exe) and importing celery works

```
>>import celery
>>
```

I have also Python 2.7 installed which does not have celery. Do you think its that?

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question. In the first code block you're most likely running your python in `C:\Python27`. In the second code block you're actually running the python with celery in it.

You should read up on managing and activating conda environments. http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/envs.html